# How to resize bootstrap button without a side-scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I am very new to CSS responsive layouts and need help structuring my navbar. I am aware that there are many other similar SO Q&As, but none of them give me the desired output.

I tried using the suggestion from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955272/how-to-make-buttons-responsive-in-bootstrap), but instead of the buttons resizing, a scrollable scrollbar appears upon window resize which is not what I want.

Here's what my HTML code looks like at the moment:

```css
.nowrap{white-space: nowrap;}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:auto;
}
.column3 {
  float: center;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: right;
}
.column4 {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: right;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://bootswatch.com/4/united/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column2"><h4 >Welcome back <span>Example</span></h4></div>
        <div class="column3">
            <h1 style="font-size:2.5vw;" title='About'>Example<span class="text-primary">TEXT</span>Example</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="column4" >
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 responsive nowrap">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Search</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" id="logoutButton " >Logout</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" >Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Summary of button requirements:**

1. The three buttons in the same row
2. Buttons responsively get smaller without the need to scroll.
3. The content in the three `<div>` tags don't overlap

Please do take into consideration that I am very new to CSS styling and so would appreciate all the constructive feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap 3 classes. Is that close to what you try to achieve?

(Edit snippet per comments:)

```css
.nowrap{white-space: nowrap;}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 text-left"><h4 >Welcome back <span>Example</span></h4></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h1 style="font-size:2.5vw;" onclick="about()" title='About'>Example<span class="text-primary">TEXT</span>Example</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive" onclick="search()" >Search</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" id="logoutButton " >Logout</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" >Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have updated my question slightly. I would like everything in one row with the welcome text centered in the left div, the example text in the center of the middle div, and the buttons centered in the right div (or as close to that as possible!). Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Newbie123 I change the classes in order to put everything on one row. Try to play with your own headers and buttons text. The other answer copy-paste example of to collapsing approach which i think you should need to use. Here a link from the official docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar